# Sockets getting emitted , however data is not getting displayed in High charts Spline

Tags: mysql, node.js, highcharts, socket.io

I am a beginner to coding using Node Js, express and Highcharts.

I am trying to connect a real time sensor data from mysql to a Highcharts Spline graph using Nodejs and express and socket.io.

Sockets are getting emitted , but the Graph doesnt show any datapoint displayed.

Appreciate your help.[Emitted Socket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNGTK.png)

app.html File :

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="graph_container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
      global: {
          useUTC: false
      }
  });

  var graph = new Highcharts.Chart({
      title: { text: 'Real Time Samples' },
      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          tickPixelInterval: 100
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: { text: 'Samples' },
          tickInterval: 10,
         // min: 0,
         // max: 100
      },
      tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name + '</b><br/>'
                    + '[ ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x)
                    + ' , '
                    + this.y + ' ]';
            }
      },
      chart: {
          type: 'spline',
          renderTo: 'graph_container',
          events: {
              load: function() {
                  var series = this.series[0];
                  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

                  socket.on('chart_data', function (sample) {
                    //add chart data to series
                     series.addPoint([sample.x * 240000, sample.y], true, false);
                  });
              }
          }
      },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: []
        }]
  });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mysql = require('mysql')

var db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'aaesnlfbl7eazw.cmk4nmbw4xhp.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
  user: 'ebroot',
  password: 'Enermo2019!',
  database: 'gateway'
});

db.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});



app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('test');
});

var device_id = 1;

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  /*
  Pada bagian ini anda bisa mengambil data live dari database dengan menggunakan mysql atau mongodb,
  pada contoh dibawah saya hanya generate random data menggunakan Math.random()
  */

  var timer = setInterval(function() {

    db.query('SELECT * FROM gateway.realdata WHERE device_id = 1 AND node_name = "Ua" ORDER BY log_dt DESC LIMIT 0, 5;', [device_id], function(err, results) {


      var x = results[0].log_dt,
        y = results[0].node_value;

      socket.emit('chart_data', {
        x: x,
        y: y
      });
      console.info("emitted: [" + x + "," + y + "]");

    });

  }, 240000); //update setiap 1 detik*/
});









http.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Hi @Inder Mukhopadhyay, What is the value of `sample` in `socket.on` callback function?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek The value I need in x is log_dt which is the timestamp in the database and y is node_value which represents the corresponding value for that timestamp. Thanks

Comment: Could you add `console.log(sample)` in that function and provide me with the result?

Comment: I am not getting any result when I do a console.log(sample)

emitted: [2019-09-17 10:42:00,400]
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server started on port 3000
Connected to database
Success
emitted: [2019-09-17 10:45:00,400]
emitted: [2019-09-17 10:45:00,400]
emitted: [2019-09-17 10:48:00,400]

-----------------------
Above is the data I am receiving

Comment: @ppotaczek I tried following this tutorial 
https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36229

Comment: so it follows that the function is not called - `addPoint` is also not called and that is why the chart is not updated.

Comment: Why is the function not called ? Which part of the code is wrong ?

Comment: I am not sure, you need to debug the code to find out. It looks like it is because of some connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is in the query callback please try after commenting the query part and send the random value in emit.
Check the logs of callback of query.

Comment: Thanks Nayan . With random values the graph is working in real time

Answer (score 0):

For highcharts to display the values, we need to convert the Date which is in String format to milliseconds using Date.parse. This worked out fine.